Javascript, map a object array to return new array
I have been looking online for a solution.  Most show you how to map an array but not an object array:


club    = [];

club[0] = {};
club[0].team        = "Manchester United";
club[0].ground  = "Old Trafford";


club[1] = {};
club[1].team        = "Manchester City";
club[1].ground  = "Etihad";

club[2] = {};
club[2].team        = "Liverpool";
club[2].ground  = "Anfield";



I want to product a new array with just the ground object key from the original object.  This eventually will include a lot more teams that can be added and deleted thus why I want to map a new array of the ground names.
I should end up with a new array:

search = ['Old Trafford', 'Etihad', 'Liverpool'];

I need to map rather that a for/next or for/each.
Thanks.

What have you tried? Doesn't let search = club.map(el => el.ground); work?  MDN docs for array Map(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

For example, if your object array is this simplified one, let club = [ { 'ground': 'theground' }, { 'ground': 'thesky' } ]; then using map() as in my previous comment should result in an array with the values of the ground keys: [ 'theground', 'thesky' ]

const club = [
{ team: "Manchester United", ground: "Old Trafford" },
{ team: "Manchester City", ground: "Etihad" },
{ team: "Liverpool", ground: "Anfield" }
];

const search = club.map(club => club.ground);

console.log(search);
// Output: ['Old Trafford', 'Etihad', 'Anfield']

